# How to get a Youtube embed livestream url using javascript without third party plugins or API?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm building a little web page that has an iframe that automatically plays a live stream from a youtube channel using the channel ID.

I need to be able to get the complete URL from that element 
([Example Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih2upOSE234)) without any third party plugins/programs or the `API`, the purpose of this is to extract the Livestream ID and display the live chat using it.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
<div>
    <iframe id="stream" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCTXma6j0F0IMEdRd4CisrIQ&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe id="adress" width="560" height="315" src=adress frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div>     
<script>
function search_id()
{    
    var url = stream.src;    
    var videoID = url.match(/(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/user\/\S+|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=))([\w\-]{10,12})\b/)[1];
    var concat = "https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=" +videoID +"&embed_domain=127.0.0.1";
    document.getElementById("adress").src = concat;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= concat;
}
</script>
    <button onclick="search_id()">Get URL</button>
</div>
```

The `var` "URL" is the one that should contain the complete URL of the live stream, the current content is just a placeholder, the `iframe` "address" is the holder for the live chat.

The reason to avoid the API it's because I can't fully comprehend how to use it (I'm attaching it anyway: [link](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCTXma6j0F0IMEdRd4CisrIQ&eventType=live&type=video&key=AIzaSyALNqt-fym5Yw4Z2pFITeLUG4BN_13afvQ)), of course, understanding how to get the *specific string* I'm looking for would be great.